# Docker Compose and Visual Studio Build Differences vs Docker CMD

Tags: visual-studio, docker, nginx

I have an issue when using `docker-compose` in Visual Studio

```
  blazor-customer:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-leestevens318}/blazor-customer:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    container_name: blazor-customer
    networks:
      - nginx_network
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - TZ=Australia/Sydney
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    #depends_on:
    #  - identity
    build:
      context: ./Client.Customer.Blazor
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/web
COPY --from=build-env /app/output/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

When building in Visual Studio here's the output:

```
Building blazor-customer
Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
 ---> b8769fe1925c
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 14cc7251b510
Step 3/6 : COPY . ./
 ---> 8bf3e8a5e2d7
Step 4/6 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output
 ---> Running in 5dc617144f52
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /app/Client.Customer.Blazor.csproj (in 6.79 sec).
  Client.Customer.Blazor -> /app/bin/Release/net5.0/Client.Customer.Blazor.dll
  Client.Customer.Blazor (Blazor output) -> /app/bin/Release/net5.0/wwwroot
  Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Compressing Blazor WebAssembly publish artifacts. This may take a while...
  Client.Customer.Blazor -> /app/output/
Removing intermediate container 5dc617144f52
 ---> 148a36ad3c05
Step 5/6 : LABEL com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio
 ---> Running in 28b7975ed37f
Removing intermediate container 28b7975ed37f
 ---> 4e8a62fd6653
Step 6/6 : LABEL com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=Client.Customer.Blazor
 ---> Running in bc2291d88cf8
Removing intermediate container bc2291d88cf8
 ---> 8bf17a0cbe3d
Successfully built 8bf17a0cbe3d
```

You can see it skips the last `FROM` in the `Dockerfile`

If i build from CMD:

```
docker build -t leestevens318/blazor-customer:latest .
```

I get the correct output (step 5 >):

```
Step 1/9 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
 ---> b8769fe1925c
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7841686380cf
Step 3/9 : COPY . ./
 ---> 351e0fd905db
Step 4/9 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output
 ---> Running in a83c2dc1928f
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /app/Client.Customer.Blazor.csproj (in 6.02 sec).
  Client.Customer.Blazor -> /app/bin/Release/net5.0/Client.Customer.Blazor.dll
  Client.Customer.Blazor (Blazor output) -> /app/bin/Release/net5.0/wwwroot
  Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Compressing Blazor WebAssembly publish artifacts. This may take a while...
  Client.Customer.Blazor -> /app/output/
Removing intermediate container a83c2dc1928f
 ---> 03528af0c0c5
Step 5/9 : FROM nginx:alpine
 ---> 629df02b47c8
Step 6/9 : WORKDIR /var/www/web
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 19608552d0c0
Step 7/9 : COPY --from=build-env /app/output/wwwroot .
 ---> 658c6e381f9c
Step 8/9 : COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> 606423b6ad6f
Step 9/9 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 86cd4ef9cc41
Removing intermediate container 86cd4ef9cc41
 ---> 6f1d1d8185cf
Successfully built 6f1d1d8185cf
```

I can't work out why the build is different from Visual Studio vs Command Line.